# How to fix this memory leak (IntentService, Runnable, ObjectBox, Repository)?

Tags: java, android, performance, memory-leaks, objectbox

I'm having an `IntentService` in which I'm **repeating** a `Runnable` **every second**.

Within the `Runnable` I'm requesting records from `MyItemsRepository`, which uses **ObjectBox**.

There is a **memory leak** somewhere. The **Android Profiler** shows a **huge consumption of "Native"**. The method `getAllByDate()` is allocated a lot.

It seems to be the leak, but I don't know how to fix that.

Any idea?
Thanks a lot in advance!

**App**

```
public class App extends Application {
    @Nullable
    private BoxStore boxStore;

    private static App instance;

    public static App getApp() {
        return instance;
    }

    public BoxStore getBoxStore() {
        if (boxStore == null) {
            boxStore = MyObjectBox.builder().androidContext(App.this).build();
        }
        return boxStore;
    }

     @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Intent service = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        this.startService(service);
    }
}
```

**MyService**

```
public class MyService extends IntentService {

    private final static String TAG = "MyService";

    @Nullable
    private Runnable runnable;

    @Nullable
    private List<Item> myItems;

    public MyService() {
        super(TAG);

        myItems = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy () {
        super.onDestroy();  
        myItems = null; // trying to get rid off the allocation?
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {        
        HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread(TAG + "_handlerThread");
        handlerThread.start();

        Handler handler  = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());
        runnable = () -> {
            try {
                processMyItems();
                if (runnable != null) {
                    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000); // restart
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                if (runnable != null) {
                    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000); // retry
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000); // first run
    }

    protected void processMyItems() throws InterruptedException, Exception {
        myItems = MyItemsRepository.getInstance().getAllByDate();

        // ... do stuff with myItems ...        
    }
}
```

**MyItemsRepository**

```
public class MyItemsRepository {

    private final static String TAG = "MyItemsRepository";

    private static MyItemsRepository instance;

    @Nullable
    private Box<MyItem> box;

    /**
     * Singleton
     * @return old or new instance
     */
    public static MyItemsRepository getInstance() {
        if (MyItemsRepository.instance == null) {
            Logger.d(TAG, "new instance");
            MyItemsRepository.instance = new MyItemsRepository();            
        }

        return MyItemsRepository.instance;
    }

    public List<MyItems> getAllByDate() {
        if (box == null) {
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }

        ElapsedTimer et = new ElapsedTimer();

        List<MyItem> items = box.query()
                .order(MyItem_.createdAt, QueryBuilder.DESCENDING)
                .build()
                .find();

        Logger.d(TAG, "getAllByDate() " + et.getElapsedMillisAsString());
        return items;
    }
}
```

**ElapsedTimer** (Helper)

```
public class ElapsedTimer {
    private long startTime;

    public ElapsedTimer() {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    public String getElapsedMillisAsString() {
        return String.format("Elapsed: %s ms", getElapsedMillis());
    }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to solve this without see what the Box class does. "getAllByDate()" uses Box Class but we don't know what it does under the hood. However using an HandleThread inside an IntentService (which has its own Thread already) is useless. Why not do a "while(true) {}" as main body of onHandleIntent() and use "Thread.sleep(1000)" to execute the same code every 1000ms?

Comment: @emandt Good point. I'll replace it by a while. Do you have a best practice for my concern? I don't think ObjectBox is leaking but my poor architecture.

Comment: Also given background restrictions in API 28+ you probably should use WorkManager instead of IntentService. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/

Comment: Sorry, totally forgot to answer: are you sure there is a memory leak? Can you actually observe memory usage increasing all the time (memory leak) or is memory use constant?

Comment: @Uwe-ObjectBox thanks for your reply! My app is leaking: it starts at 30MB and ends at 800-900MB after a few hours. I never had a "out of memory" though. Maybe because I've too much memory. :) I don't think it's ObjectBox itself, but my lack of knowledge.

Comment: Just set up a little project which also continuously queries for objects. Though native memory rises and is then freed as expected. So yes, there is probably another issue causing the leak. Anyhow, if you find in your tests that it is an ObjectBox issue, please share an example project with us so it can be fixed!

Comment: @Uwe-ObjectBox I can't finally confirm yet, but it looks like I just had to call `App.getApp().getBoxStore().boxFor(MyItem.class).closeThreadResources();` before the thread ends. The memory consumption seems to be highly reduced now.